# Installing web3 for Ethereum error

Tags: javascript, python, json, blockchain, ethereum

I'm using MacOS and is trying to install web3. I'm getting this error response message which I'm not sure how to resolve.

I have other code editors installed in my mac, and currently I'm learning how to do some blockchain development. Would be really helpful if someone could assist me in this. Thanks!

```
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /Users/HTT/inbox/node_modules/scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install /Users/HTT/inbox/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/anaconda3/bin/python" is v3.6.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failPythonVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:492:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:474:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:267:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/HTT/inbox/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/HTT/.npm/_logs/2018-04-26T14_03_17_140Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by specifying the version. Not really a "fix", but working with stable releases is something I can get behind

```
npm install -g web3@0.20.6
```

I have also seen that this will do the trick

```
npm install ethereum/web3.js
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this command to check the python version :

`python --version`

Because you need to use node-gyp, it is recommended to install python2.7.